# Simple Asynctask not working and throwing errors at me

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have built the following simple Asynctask:

```
package com.example.helloworld;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.AsyncTask;

public class HelloWorldActivity extends Activity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    private class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void doInBackground(Void... res) {}

    }
}
```

But it gives me error:

```
[javac] /home/gizkp/happ/src/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldActivity.java:17: error: HelloWorldActivity.SimpleTask is not abstract and does not override abstract method doInBackground(String...) in AsyncTask
[javac]     private class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
[javac]             ^
[javac] /home/gizko/happ/src/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldActivity.java:20: error: doInBackground(String...) in HelloWorldActivity.SimpleTask cannot override doInBackground(Params...) in AsyncTask
[javac]         protected void doInBackground(String... res) {}
[javac]                        ^
[javac]   return type void is not compatible with String
[javac]   where Params,Result are type-variables:
[javac]     Params extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
[javac]     Result extends Object declared in class AsyncTask
[javac] /home/gizko/happ/src/com/example/helloworld/HelloWorldActivity.java:19: error: method does not override or implement a method from a supertype
[javac]         @Override
[javac]         ^
[javac] 3 errors
```

I don't understand what is going wrong with such a simple code. I've also tried changing Asynctask parameters without any success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change the return type of the doInBackground from **void** to **Void** and see if it works

Comment: It kinda works but still throws errors at me. For it to work without compilation errors I have to put a return too.

Comment: @gizko yea of course, you can return null and it will work then

Answer (score 0):

your implementation of `void doInBackground(Void... res) {}` method is wrong.

As mentioned in error its not successfully overriding `doInBackground` method because of return type.

Try this

```
public class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
    {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `void` to `Void` as follows:

```
private class SimpleTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: It works if I put return too! I thought return wasn't necessary. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

try this buddy : much easier and works well:

```
public class RunAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    private static final String TAG = "RunAsyncTask";
    ProgressDialog processingDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "loading...", true);
    String responseEntity;

    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... nothing) {
        Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground");

        HttpClient client       = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost postRequest    = new HttpPost(new String("http://api.com"));


        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("data", "data"));             


        int responseCode = 0;
        responseEntity = "-";

        try 
          {
            UrlEncodedFormEntity ent = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params, "UTF-8");

            postRequest.setEntity(ent);
            HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(postRequest);

            responseCode    = responsePOST.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
            responseEntity  = EntityUtils.toString(responsePOST.getEntity()).trim();
        } 
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }


        if((200 == responseCode) && (responseEntity.length() == 0)) { return true; } 
        else { return false; }

        return true;

    }//end doInBackground

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        if(null != processingDialog) { processingDialog.dismiss(); }

        if (true == result){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "true", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();//                
        } else{ Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "false", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  }


        textResult.setText("");
        textResult.setText(formatString(responseEntity));


    }//end onPostExecute
}
```